# Count non-NA values by group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, na

Here is my example

```
mydf<-data.frame('col_1' = c('A','A','B','B'), 'col_2' = c(100,NA, 90,30))
```

I would like to group by `col_1` and count non-`NA` elements in `col_2`

I would like to do it with `dplyr`. Here is what I tried:

```
mydf %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise_each(funs(!is.na(col_2)))
mydf %>% group_by(col_1) %>% mutate(non_na_count = length(col_2, na.rm=TRUE))
mydf %>% group_by(col_1) %>% mutate(non_na_count = count(col_2, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use this

```
mydf %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(col_2)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   col_1 non_na_count
  <fctr>        <int>
1      A            1
2      B            2
```

Comment: For getting a summary for all columns, use `summarise_all(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))`

Comment: If applying another summary function to col_2, be careful which order you request the calculations.
`my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(col_1 = mean(col_1, na.rm = T), non_na_count = sum(!is.na(col_2)))`
produces a difference result than
`my_df %>% group_by(col_1) %>% summarise(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(col_2)), col_1 = mean(col_1, na.rm = T))`

Comment: @zack I get identical results for both orders (I am using dplyr version 0.8.99.9002 from github).

Comment: @RichardTelford I made a mistake in typing my comment. Instead of `col_1 = mean(col_1, na.rm = T)` in the call to `summarise`, try `col_2 = mean(col_2, na.rm = T)`.  Using dplyr version 0.8.3, I get different results.

Comment: Why does it work with the sum function because it is counting?

Comment: The `!is.na()` converts the data to TRUE/FALSE. sum() treats the TRUE as 1 and the FALSE as 0, so the sum is the count of the not NA values

Answer (score 8):

We can  `filter` the NA elements in 'col_2' and then do a `count` of 'col_1'

```
mydf %>%
     filter(!is.na(col_2))  %>%
      count(col_1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   col_1     n
#  <fctr> <int>
#1      A     1
#2      B     2
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(col_2))), col_1]
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(col_2 = !is.na(col_2))~col_1, mydf, sum)
#  col_1 col_2
#1     A     1
#2     B     2
```

Or using `table`

```
table(mydf$col_1[!is.na(mydf$col_2)])
```

Comment: Why isn't the last answer using table: table(mydf$col_1[ , ! is.na(mydf$col_2)])?

Answer (score 5):

```
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame("col_1" = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                   "col_2" = c(100, NA, 90, 30))

mydf %>%
  group_by(col_1) %>%
  select_if(function(x) any(is.na(x))) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.)))) -> NA_mydf

kable(NA_mydf)
```